# VS project references keep breaking, even after successful add

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a 10 project solution in VS. I have one web project that is not compiling due to errors that state that referenced classes do not exist.

When I click on the file of the error, I see the red lines indicating missing references, but after opening the file, the errors disappear. I repeat until all errors are solved, but build still failing.

I go check references and note the yellow icon on the referenced projects within my failing project build. I once again remove the references, then re-add the project references (they are in the solution).

I Clean, Rebuild, still same stuff. No errors, failed build.

Answer (score 0):

(posted to answer)

Turns out that the projects I was referencing were using a different Target Framework! Once I updated the referencing project to match the target, it worked.

I didn't see this error anywhere, and was very confused. So hope this helps someone.